# Unable to run docker container

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core

I want to run my .NET MVC application into a docker image: but I'm unable to test it.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /DataHandlerService

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /DataHandlerService
COPY --from=build-env /DataHandlerService/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DataHandlerService.dll"]
```

the image builds successfully but when I run `docker container run datahandler` here is what I get:

> {"EventId":60,"LogLevel":"Warning","Category":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository","Message":"Storing
> keys in a directory \u0027/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys\u0027 that
> may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be
> unavailable when container is destroyed.","State":{"Message":"Storing
> keys in a directory \u0027/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys\u0027 that
> may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be
> unavailable when container is
> destroyed.","path":"/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys","{OriginalFormat}":"Storing
> keys in a directory \u0027{path}\u0027 that may not be persisted
> outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when
> container is destroyed."}}
> {"EventId":35,"LogLevel":"Warning","Category":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager","Message":"No
> XML encryptor configured. Key {90a759c1-0f7a-417f-90e1-6b46c6f05b6a}
> may be persisted to storage in unencrypted
> form.","State":{"Message":"No XML encryptor configured. Key
> {90a759c1-0f7a-417f-90e1-6b46c6f05b6a} may be persisted to storage in
> unencrypted
> form.","KeyId":"90a759c1-0f7a-417f-90e1-6b46c6f05b6a","{OriginalFormat}":"No
> XML encryptor configured. Key {KeyId:B} may be persisted to storage in
> unencrypted form."}}
> {"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now
> listening on: http://[::]:80","State":{"Message":"Now listening on:
> http://[::]:80","address":"http://[::]:80","{OriginalFormat}":"Now
> listening on: {address}"}}
> {"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Application
> started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut
> down.","State":{"Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to
> shut down.","{OriginalFormat}":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC
> to shut down."}}
> {"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Hosting
> environment: Production","State":{"Message":"Hosting environment:
> Production","envName":"Production","{OriginalFormat}":"Hosting
> environment: {envName}"}}
> {"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Content
> root path: /DataHandlerService/","State":{"Message":"Content root
> path:
> /DataHandlerService/","contentRoot":"/DataHandlerService/","{OriginalFormat}":"Content
> root path: {contentRoot}"}}

Comment: Ok, these are warnings and info messages, but they should not hinder you to run the container. Are there any errors? The logs explictily state, that your asp.net app is running: `Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","{OriginalFormat}":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down."}}` What outout do you get when you run `docker ps`? Is your container running?

Comment: `CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS      NAMES 

b364912f4b07   datahandler-service   "dotnet DataHandlerS…"   20 minutes ago   Up 20 minutes   7242/tcp   datahandler-service` 
This is the output of  `docker ps`

Comment: but I can't connect to `http://localhost:7242/`

Comment: You need to map your container port to an available port on your host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't map any ports when you run it, so you can't reach the container. Your container seems to run fine aside from that.

Try

```
docker run -p 7242:80 -d datahandler
```

Then you should be able to get to the app at http://localhost:7242/